# React hook useRender called twice if bailing and setting state afterward

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, use-reducer, react-lifecycle-hooks

I'm not sure if this is expected behavior, but if you bail out of a dispatch (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-dispatch) while using the useReducer hook, the action occurs twice if it's followed by a render. Let me explain:

```
// bailing out to prevent re-rendering
const testReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD":
      state.test += 1
      return state;
  }
};

const myComponent = () => {
  let [totalClicks, setClicks] = useState(0);
    const [state, setState] = useReducer(testReducer, {
      test: 0,
    });

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setState({type: 'ADD'});
    setClicks((totalClicks += 1));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>+</button>
      <p>{totalClicks}</p>
      <p>test count: {state.test}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When you click the button, state.test goes up by 2, while totalClicks increases by 1. **However, if I were to change the reducer so that it doesn't bail to one like below, they would both increase by 1.**

```
// non-bailing reducer
const testReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD":
      return {
        test: state.test + 1,
      };
  }
};
```

Why is this? And is this expected behavior or a bug?
sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-robinson-dds63?file=/src/App.js

---

**UPDATE:**
after doing some debugging, it looks like this behavior only occurs when wrapped with a **React.StrictMode**

Does anyone know what causes this???

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example for this. I created one and didn't find any issue. https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-state-non-pure-update-d83uo

Comment: Attached. After looking at yours I don't understand the difference of what I was doing and why mine is behaving this way. https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-robinson-dds63?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc of StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects), react intentionally calls reducer function with same action twice, so to expose unnoticed potentially harmful side-effects, which is exactly what happens to your case.

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions: […] Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer

Comment: Wow that's interesting. So what about the example is unsafe? Is it the fact that we're updating our useState state and our useReducer state on the same click event?

Comment: It’s about you violating the presumption that reducer should be side-effect free, idempotent, and always returns new value when there’s a change. You break the 3rd rule (intentionally though). To me that’s more like a convention to begin with. But since there’s a whole bunch of ecosystems and mechanisms (like the bailout) built around this presumption, it becomes a requirement. So strictMode decides to expose it.